# How to find min&max in array push

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am doing a api for cab booking app like uber.I am using distancematrix to find the distance between two latitude and longitude.In that single customer have multiple drivers around it.I would like to find nearest driver using single  customer latitude and longitude over multiple driver latitude and longitude.How can i find min&max distance of driver and get min&max value based on driver id.

Below code i am using to find the nearest driver:

```
<?php
        function GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2)
        {
            $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&language=pl-PL";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $response_a = json_decode($response, true);
            $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
            $time = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];

            return array('distance' => $dist, 'time' => $time);
            //return $distance;
        }

    $cus_latlong_qry="SELECT * FROM customer_position WHERE customer_id='$customer_id'";
    $cus_latlong_exe=mysqli_query($con,$cus_latlong_qry);
    $cus_latlong_res=mysqli_fetch_array($cus_latlong_exe);
    $cus_lat=$cus_latlong_res['latitude'];
    $cus_long=$cus_latlong_res['longtitude'];

$driver_latlong_qry="SELECT * FROM driver_position WHERE driver_type='$_GET[type_id]' AND (booking_status='3' OR booking_status='2') AND active_status='0'";

                $driver_latlong_exe=mysqli_query($con,$driver_latlong_qry);
                $minimumvalue=array();
                $distance=array();
                while($driver_latlong_res=mysqli_fetch_array($driver_latlong_exe))
                {
                    $driv_id=$driver_latlong_res['driver_id'];
                    $driv_lat=$driver_latlong_res['lattitude'];
                    $driv_long=$driver_latlong_res['longtitude'];
                    $dist = GetDrivingDistance($cus_lat,$driv_lat,$cus_long,$driv_long);
                    array_push($distance,$dist);
                }

?>
```

here how can i find min&mx distance in array push with respect to particular driver id..??

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic, collect min & max values:

```
$drivers = array();    

 while($driver_latlong_res=mysqli_fetch_array($driver_latlong_exe))
 {
  $driv_id=$driver_latlong_res['driver_id'];                  
  $driv_lat=$driver_latlong_res['lattitude'];               
  $driv_long=$driver_latlong_res['longtitude']; 
  $dist = GetDrivingDistance($cus_lat,$driv_lat,$cus_long,$driv_long);

  array_push($distance[$driv_id], $dist);

  $drivers[$driv_id]['min'] = min($distance[$driv_id]);     
  $drivers[$driv_id]['max'] = max($distance[$driv_id]);

 }

print_r($drivers);
```

As a result you will get `$drivers` array where first key is driver_id, and as a second key you will have min and max values for him.

Comment: it give the error message:array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: before pushing initialize array `$distance[$driv_id] = array();`

Comment: there is no sorting happen?? Array
(
    [HCB-1] => Array
        (
            [min] => 14.6
        )

    [HCB-3] => Array
        (
            [min] => 1
        )

    [HCB-2] => Array
        (
            [min] => 16.4
        )

)

Comment: sorting? No. Each driver has his min value. If you want you can echo each value in loop and verify.

Comment: how to get output like this :{
"MINIMUM": [{
    "min": "3.6",
    "driverid": "HCB-6"
}]}

Comment: To achieve this you should do some further coding. However it is not the scope of this question. You have asked about: "How can i find min&max distance of driver and get min&max value based on driver" this was explained - I'd like you to accept and vote-up my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use min & max`enter code here`

```
min($distance[$driv_id]);     
max($distance[$driv_id]);
```